# MVC app referencing my library fails at runtime, but my console app referencing the same library succeeds

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, dll

I have a Visual Studio solution (all code in `C#`) that has the structure:

```
MySolution
|
+--MyLibrary (DLL library)
|
+--MyMVCSite (MVC 5 site)
|
+--MyConsoleApp (Console app)
```

`MyLibrary` references the **[Emgu.CV](http://www.emgu.com)**  DLLs, which are a set of `C#` wrappers for the unmanaged library `OpenCV`. And I have all the OpenCV dlls being "Copy always" to the bin directory on building.

Now here is the issue. In `MyConsoleApp`, `program.cs`, I have the code:

```
MyLibrary mylib = new MyLibrary();
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"c:\\cat.jpg");
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    arr = ms.ToArray();
    mylib.Process(arr);
}
```

which calls the `MyLibrary` code:

```
public void Process(byte[] buffer) {
    PreprocessImage(buffer, true);
}

private Image<Gray, byte> PreprocessImage(byte[] buffer, bool resize) {

    Image<Gray, byte> grayImage;
    using (MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream(buffer)) {
        Bitmap bmpImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(mss);

        Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmpImage); // <-- Emgu.CV type
        // More processing on img

    }
}
```

and everything **succeeds**. The variable `img` (which is built via Emgu.CVs wrapper functions to OpenCV) is set correctly and can be processed downstream, etc.

**HOWEVER**, when I try to repeat the exact same code from `MyConsoleApp` in the `HomeController.cs` of `MyMVCSite` using the code (in `HomeController.cs`), I get a runtime error on the line: `Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmpImage);` stating `{"Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core300': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}`

Both `MyConsoleApp` `MyMVCSite` reference `MyLibrary`, yet the console app works and the MVC app does not, despite using the same exact code to call `MyLibrary`. **Does anyone have any idea what could be going on?** I repeated this in a barebones project, and the behavior is still see the same thing.

**UPDATE**

I've posted my barebones project that shows this behavior at: https://github.com/brspurri/Test
Still at a total loss here.

Comment: I'm guessing the MyMVCSite has settings included that the console does not, and under the hood it tries to load more things in.  Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509702/installing-opencv-highgui-missing?

Comment: I agree, there must be a setting difference, possible related to my visual studio settings. I'm not sure though, and I don't even know where to begin to look. Any advice? The SO question you suggested doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Thanks for retired the negative points in my answer, I find the response, EnguCv don't work with IIS Express, change the project properties to use Local IIS, more details in my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634157/how-use-emgucv-in-a-mvc-net-project/27080126#27080126)